# How to combine these If statement conditions

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, if-statement

I am new to OOP as a whole let alone VB. I'm trying to turn the following 4 lines into just 2 lines by combining the conditions:

```
ElseIf GA_URI.StartsWith("/home/index") Then
    gaCategory = cat_splash

ElseIf GA_URI = "/games" Then
    gaCategory = cat_splash
```

I have tried this:

```
ElseIf GA_URI.StartsWith("/home/index") And GA_URI = "/games" Then
    gaCategory = cat_splash
```

But not working.
Any help is hugely appreciated

Comment: I'm not starting a new project, I'm adding to it while the dev is away

Comment: Okay, I didn't mean that C# is **better** than VB(.net) - and in your case there is no other choice. But for learning OOP from scratch, C# appears much cleaner (to me).

Comment: @Michael _smarter syntax_ that statement is purely personal. I do both and in the context of .Net (not to mention the OP's question), as Dave Rook stated, one isn't "better" than the other. You can _personally prefer_ one over the other based on your own perceptions.

Comment: Yes, after rethinking my statement: You're both right. (I had in mind: Would anyone start a new project by using Delphi? :) )

Comment: @Michael Not that I know Delphi but why not? If the current resource has mastery of it, then decisions aren't that simple to add a learning curve to the project. But I think we're digressing. Point taken :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest [OrElse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so you can be more efficient with short circuiting (don't have to eval both expresssions):

```
ElseIf GA_URI.StartsWith("/home/index") OrElse GA_URI = "/games" Then
   gaCategory = cat_splash
```

---

### Update:

> *Q: Would this work for more than 2 expressions? as I have cases where I
>   may have 3 or more*

Sure:

```
ElseIf GA_URI.StartsWith("/home/index") OrElse 
    (GA_URI = "/games" OrElse GA_URI = "/foo")
Then 
     gaCategory = cat_splash
...
```

You can keep going (parenthetical expressions) but at some point [`Select...Case`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be the way to go.

Comment: Would this work for more than 2 expressions? as I have cases where I may have 3 or more

Answer (score 3):

replace And with Or and can write it as

```
         ElseIf GA_URI.StartsWith("/home/index") Or GA_URI = "/games" Then
       gaCategory = cat_splash
```

Because in you want if the `GA_URI starts with /home/index` or `GA_URI is /games` then in any of the condition you want the gaCategory = cat_splash so we need to use `OR instead of And`. to validate any of the condition is true then assign the **gaCategory = cat_splash**

Answer (score 3):

You need to use OR, it can't be both locations

```
ElseIf GA_URI.StartsWith("/home/index") Or GA_URI = "/games" Then
   gaCategory = cat_splash
```

By using AND, you're saying it must start with `"/home/index"` AND must be `"/games"`. Well, this will never be true.

By changing to OR, you're saying it can either start with `"/home/index"` OR be `"/games"`.

Comment: Thanks, Final version is `ElseIf GA_URI.StartsWith("/home/index") Or GA_URI = "/games" Or GA_URI = "/games/" Then...`

Comment: It would probably be better to use OrElse instead of just Or as it will short circuit.  Or will still work in this situation, of course, but I believe it is considered a best practice to use OrElse.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
ElseIf GA_URI.StartsWith("/home/index") Or GA_URI = "/games" Then
    gaCategory = cat_splash
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ElseIf GA_URI.StartsWith("/home/index") OR GA_URI = "/games" Then
    gaCategory = cat_splash
```

would surely do the trick, because the path can only be one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Or](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06s37a7f.aspx) instead of [And](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh.aspx)

```
ElseIf GA_URI.StartsWith("/home/index") Or GA_URI = "/games" Then
    gaCategory = cat_splash
```